# Meaning of おめでとさん

Tags: meaning, manga, sports

During a boxing match a spectator is congratulating a boxer for winning the previous match saying this sentence:

> ２回戦突破おめでとさん

What is the meaning of おめでとさん? He his clearly congratulating the guy, so I think it must come from おめでとう, but why the omission of the う and the addition of さん? I don't think it could really be the guy's name.

[Here you can see the whole page where it is taken from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBABy.jpg) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Internetを調べると「おめでとう**さま** 」という例はありますが、あまり正しい日本語ではありません。しかし、「おつかれ**さま** 」、「ごくろう**さま** 」や「ごちそう**さま** 」のように「さま」をつける表現は普通に使われています。

Comment: ↑　上記のコメントは、「おめでとさん」に対するYubal Satoさんの回答が正しい（+1 upvote）とした上で、更に「さま」をつける表現もあるという例の紹介です。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of ways to say おめでとう more friendlily. The closest translation would be congrats?
There're similar type of words like ごくろうさん, おつかれさん, and　ありがとさん.